# Find out the Old Date from a date column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How the find the oldest values from the datetime column?

I have table with datetime column (UpdateDate), and i need to find out the oldest data based on the UpdateDate .

```
Id     UpdateDate                   Desc
-----------------------------------------
1    2010-06-15 00:00:00.000       aaaaa
2    2009-03-22 00:00:00.000       bbbbb
3    2008-01-12 00:00:00.000       ccccc
4    2008-02-12 00:00:00.000       ddddd 
5    2009-04-03 00:00:00.000       eeeee
6    2010-06-12 00:00:00.000       fffff
```

I have Find out the old year dates from the  current date using 
`Select UpdateDate from Table1 where DATEDIFF(YEAR,UpdateDate,getdate()) > 0` Query. But I need to find out the 2008th data only (Since the 2008 is the oldest one here) 
I dont know what is there in the Table I need find out the Oldest date values.. How is it Possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select UpdateDate from Table1 where DATEDIFF(YEAR,PartDateCol,getdate()) IN
(Select MAX(DATEDIFF(YEAR,PartDateCol,GETDATE())) DiffYear from Table1)
```

This will return two record of 2008. If your records has four 2006 date than it return all 2006 data if difference is large.

Comment: Ya... This is what i am expected.. Thanks a lot dude.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data that within 2008 year try this:

```
Select UpdateDate From Table1 
Where Year(UpdateDate) = 
(
   Select Year(UpdateDate) 
   from Table1 Order By UpdateDate ASC Limit 1
) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But What i need is that, i dont know whether 2008 is the oldest one. I know only the table name and it contains some date values, from that i need to find out the oldest dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [top](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) and [order by](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx).

```
select top(1) UpdateDate
from Table1
order by UpdateDate
```

**Update:**

If you want all rows for the first year present you can use this instead.

```
select *
from (
      select *,
             rank() over(order by year(UpdateDate)) as rn
      from Table1
     ) as T
where T.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is

`Select UpdateDate from Table1 where YEAR(UpdateDate )=2008`

But, you can find out the oldest dates by ordering the data as such

`Select * from Table1 order by UpdateDate ASC`